# Trying to ping windows host uing ansible, but not successfull

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x, ansible-inventory, ansible-facts

I am trying to ping windows host from using ansible, but unable to ping.

getting below errors:

```
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {
    "changed": false,
    "module_stderr": "#< CLIXML\r\n<Objs Version=\"1.1.0.1\" xmlns=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/powershell/2004/04\"><S S=\"Error\">invalid payload_x000D__x000A_</S><S S=\"Error\">At line:4 char:44_x000D__x000A_</S><S S=\"Error\">+ If (-not $split_parts.Length -eq 2) { throw &lt;&lt;&lt;&lt;  \"invalid payload\" }_x000D__x000A_</S><S S=\"Error\">    + CategoryInfo          : OperationStopped: (invalid payload:String) [], R _x000D__x000A_</S><S S=\"Error\">   untimeException_x000D__x000A_</S><S S=\"Error\">    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : invalid payload_x000D__x000A_</S><S S=\"Error\"> _x000D__x000A_</S></Objs>",
    "module_stdout": "",
    "msg": "MODULE FAILURE\nSee stdout/stderr for the exact error",
    "rc": 1
}
```

Inventory file:

```
[winnode] 
localhost
```

group_vars:

```
ansible_port: 5985
ansible_connection: winrm
ansible_user: XXXXX
ansible_password: XXXXXX
ansible_winrm_scheme: http
ansible_winrm_kerberos_delegation: true
```

Playbook.yml:

```
  - hosts: winnode
  gather_facts: no
  tasks:
    - name: "ping host"
      win_ping:
      register: download_result
    - name: "display result"
      debug:
        var: download_result
```

By using `win_rm` I am trying to access playbook in windows,  but I am getting issues.

telnet is working for post 5985, able to connect telnet, but by using ansible unable to connect and get the result of ping command.

Comment: Are you trying on localhost? Is ansible server itself windows?

Answer (score 0):

In my case, this is due to being on an older version of PowerShell which is incompatible with Ansible.  This is common if you are using Windows Server 2008.

[image: Image of powershell version]

You will want to follow these instructions for upgrading:

https://www.rootusers.com/install-powershell-5-windows-server-2008-r2/

As a prerequisite, you will also need to install .NET Framework 4.5.2 or later, which is also included in the post in the above link.